# How to assign value in protected set declaration like creatorId in abp io .net

Tags: c#, .net, abp

I am using .net abp io. I have a problem to assign a protected set like creatorId. Below is the sample:

`public virtual Guid? CreatorId { get; protected set; }` 
My code in service :

```
var status = new rejectStatus()`
  {
   Id = query.Id,
   RejectDate = DateTime.Now,  
   CreatorId = query.CreatorId
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to set the ```CreatorId``` yourself? It is automatically populated for you by Abp. If you share your specific need, maybe there would be another solution than setting it?